# Programatic Query Weighting

Tags: algorithm, filtering, probability

Here's a puzzle I'm trying to solve for an application I am anticipating developing. Imagine a dating app where people can search for individuals by nationality.

Person An is on the app and is 10% interested in meeting Russians and 90% interested in meeting Mexicans.
Person B is searching on the app and is 90% interested in meeting Russians and 10% interested in meeting Mexicans.

It's fairly straightforward to make each person's OWN search results match their preference. For example, for Person B, if you want 100 total results for their search, run 2 queries, and join the result set. The first query generates 90 Russians and the second query generates 10 Mexicans for a total of 100 results which accurately reflect Person B's preference of 90% Russians and 10% Mexicans.

In that example though, Person A will likely ALWAYS show up in Person B's result set (assuming all other criteria match) since Person A has some interest in meeting Russians. But ideally Person A should really only show up in Person B's result set more like 10% of the time since that more closely reflects their OWN preference. In other words, if there are 1,000 people on the app all interested in meeting Russians, you don't really want Person A to be overwhelmed with hundreds of requests from many of those people interested in meeting Russians when Person B really only has a 10% interest in meeting Russians.

Is there a logical programmatic way to account for that properly? It feels like it should be some kind of weighting or probability solution but I just can't seem to get my arms around it. Note that I'm not really concerned about the technology (e.g. SQL) if you want to share a code example. I'm more interested in how to *think* about the solution so that I can incorporate it into any kind of code. The only solution I can currently think of is to maintain some kind of interim "usage" table but that is definitely inelegant and cumbersome.

Comment: This is a variation of the "stable marriage problem". The idea is to match requests with preferences in a way that yields no pair of matched pairs who would improve their situation by reversing partners. You can use "stable marriage" as a search term to learn how this is handled algorithmically.  Your variation is interesting, but it shouldn't be too hard to handle.

Comment: Thank you!  I didn't know that my dilemma had such a "famous" background, lol.  ;-)  But it just goes to prove that old adage that there's nothing (or at least not much) new under the sun....  It looks like I've got some reading to do to come up-to-speed on this.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you want to order by the probability that the two are suited for each other.  This would be something like:

```
order by p(a|b))*p(b|a) desc
```

p(a|b) is the probability of a given the characteristics of b.  So, for a and Russians this is 90%.  The p(b|a) is the opposite, so this ends up as (0.1)*(0.9) = 0.09.  If they both approved 100%, then this would be 1.0.  If either is 0%, then the result is 0%.

This is my first guess on a suitable measure, but it seems reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

@Gordon Linoff

Okay I'm following the *logic* of what you're saying but I'm still a little fuzzy on what that would look like when applied to code (probability is a pretty fuzzy area for me).  Can you give me a quick example of what you mean?  Here's a simple set up:

Given an example database table with the following structure:

Table "Preferences"

- pPersonLetter        varchar(25)
- pRussianPreference   numeric
- pMexicanPreference   numeric

Running the query:

```
SELECT pPersonLetter, pRussianPreference, pMexicanPreference
FROM Preferences
```

would yield something like:

```
pPersonLetter, pRussianPreference, pMexicanPreference
Person A, .1, .9
Person B, .9, .1
Person C, .5, .5
Person D, 1, 0
.
.
.
```

Using the example set up from the original post:

> Person A is on the app and is 10% interested in meeting Russians and
>   90% interested in meeting Mexicans. Person B is searching on the app
>   and is 90% interested in meeting Russians and 10% interested in
>   meeting Mexicans.

Incorporating your answer, what would the SQL query look like to generate the list for Person B?  Although I know it is incorrect as written, I want to say based on your post that it should be something like:

```
SELECT pPersonLetter, pRussianPreference, pMexicanPreference
FROM Preferences
ORDER BY p(a|b))*p(b|a) DESC
```

But I know that doesn't work both from a syntax perspective and a logic perspective (i.e. I don't think I'm reflecting either person's preferences either by joining two queries, as in my original example, or by including an appropriate "WHERE" clause)---but hopefully this is a simple enough example for my learning purposes....  I think that what's throwing me off is I'm not quite sure what the "p" refers to (i.e. whether or not it is some kind of SQL function or is meant to be a column name like pPersonLetter) and I'm generally unfamiliar with the "|" operator (which I think is a Bitwise operator perhaps?).

Given the example table and data above, is there a simple SQL query that would work and incorporate your answer?  That might help me get my arms around this a little better....